# What are the example of "repeated cross-section" and "two cross-sectional dimensions"?

Tags: econometrics

[Borusyak, 2021](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/b1e55330-f605-363c-b07f-3ab67325e929/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B47d22c8f-e7ba-3ead-9833-eeae8a94d5f0%7D) has a sentence

> In Section 5 we consider extensions to repeated cross-sections, data
> defined by two cross-sectional dimensions (e.g. regions and age
> groups), triple-differences designs, and other data structures

I am wondering if there is any intuitive explanation and example for "two cross-sectional dimensions" and "repeated cross-section".

Comment: The title does not quite match the body. Are you interested in repeated cross sections or in two cross-sectional dimensions?

Comment: @RichardHardy, I am confused about both